# Describe the set $A(r)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z=\exp(1/s),0<|s|<r\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have the next problem:

1. Let $r>0$, describe the set $A(r)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z=\exp(1/s),0<|s|<r\}$.
2. Is it possible to prove that $A(r) = \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$?

What i tried was:

\begin{equation*}
            \begin{split}
                A(r)
                &=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z=\exp(1/w),0<|w|<r\}\\
                &=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z=\exp(1/w),0<|w|<r\}\\
                &=\{\exp(z)\in\mathbb{C}:z=1/w,0<|w|<r\}\\
                &=\{\exp(z)\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>1/r\}\\
                &=\{\exp(z)\in\mathbb{C}:z\in[D(0,1/r)]^c\}\\
                &=\text{Im}(\exp:\mathbb{C}\setminus D(0,1/r)\to\mathbb{C})
            \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Then $A(r)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\exp(w)=z,w\in[D(0,1/r)]^c\}$. I see that it is the image through the exponential, and that it does not have the origin, then I get that
$$A(r) \subseteq \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$$
But I can't see how to get the other inclusion, any hints or ideas?

Comment: what do you know about the periodicity of the exp function?

Comment: The exp function is representable by sin and cos function, but i don't see how that can help. I see that we have the inclusion as a function of r, so it is not necessarily reached (2)

Comment: Huge hint: $exp(z)=exp(z+2\pi i)$

Comment: This answers 
your question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2672442/prove-picards-theorem-for-f-zeta-e1-zeta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that $A=\{e^z\in\mathbb{C}: z \in \Bbb C, |z|>1/r\}$ is equal to $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

As you said, $A \subseteq \Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$ holds because the exponential function does not take the value zero.

For the other direction, let $w$ be a non-zero complex number, and let $z$ be *any* logarithm of $w$. Then for all integers $k$
$$
 e^{z+2k\pi} = e^z = w
$$
and for sufficently large $k$ is $|z+2k\pi| > 1/r$. This demonstrates that $w \in A$.